# Ajax code to mysql is causing High Server Load in a High Traffic Site

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a standalone script, who  makes an Ajax request  to the Wordpress database every time an user visits my site, this is causing high server load every time I have a lot of visits at the same time in my site.

This is for a Linux server with 6 CPU of 2.20GHz, 8 GB of RAM and content is cached with Cloudflare. My script is the only dynamic content of the site.

Ajax Request:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
   type: 'POST',
   url: myurl,
   data: { 'ubicacion' : 'content'},
      success: function(output) {
         //do stuff
      }
   });
```

PHP:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-load.php');
global $wpdb; 

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE row = 123" ); 
echo $user_count;
```

I'm not having problems with the results, but when my site have high peaks of visits, the server load increases a lot.

Comment: is `row` indexed?

Comment: In addition to properly indexing your DB --  It worthwhile to mention that a separated DB server with failover is recommended for "high traffic" sites.

Comment: @tim yes, row is indexed :s